# Weird Mongoose. I get crap from findOne's doc.

Tags: mongodb, node.js, find, mongoose, doc

Here is what my script look like:

```
UserModel.findOne(
 {userId:'xx123456'},
  function(err, doc) {
   if (err) {
    next(err);
   } else if (! doc) {
    next( 'findOne: User not found. Input: ' + JSON.stringify(data)));
   } else {
    next(null, {status:true, 
     message:'User is found' ,
     data:doc
   });
  }
 }
);
```

When I run unit test in command line, doc is the mongo Document. e.g. {userId:'xx123456', name:"My Name' }

However, when I make a web app calling this function passing exactly the same userId, doc.userId is empty. However, I can find the data in doc._doc why is that?

I have another site that return the full document from "doc" normally. Why there is inconsistency...

I have to do this to normalize the data: if (docs) docs = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(docs));

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what's happening, but I'd first try a UserModel.find({}); Do this to see what, if anything, returns. If nothing returns you have a problem.

Also, one issue I've seen is that Mongoose is case sensitive. Make sure 'userId' is not supposed to be something like 'userid.' Command line will work (as far as I've seen) with the wrong case. Mongoose / Node will not.

Comment: the weird thing is.. i get the data. but not in doc, but in doc._doc